# Jquery FullCalendar - Disable resize on Single Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery FullCalendar.

Can I check that if my Event is on single date ( I mean no end date, just start date ), so in that case it should not be resizable. How can I do that ?

**For Example:**

If I have this criteria : 2013-12-03 to 2013-12-10     ***THIS SHOULD RESIZE***

If I have this criteria : 2013-12-03                   ***THIS SHOULD NOT RESIZE***

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can do that. It would be something like this :

First use this [eventAfterAllRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) and inside it use this [clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) to fetch all your events, or you can set the event propertie [editable](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) for each event server side, your choice. But if not if you prefer do it client side ( i would not recomend that ), here's a function that might help you on your way:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   ...
   eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element) {
     turnEventsEditable();
   },
   ...
 });


 //Special function
 function turnEventsEditable(){

    var events = new Array();       
    events = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents');

        foreach(var e in events){

        if(e.end != "" || e.end != null){

             e.editable = true;

            }else{
             //just to make sure;
             e.editable = false;
            }

        }

    return events;                 
    }
```